# How do I save all attachments to an entry?

Tags: cognito-forms

Is it possible to save all attachments to an entry without having to download each one individually?

Answer (score 1):

Right now the best way to get bulk access to uploaded files is to use our [Zapier integration](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/integrations) support to push uploaded files into your favorite cloud storage service.  These uploaded files are linked back to the source entry.

We are also considering [bulk export options](https://trello.com/c/RBSfDsPl) for file attachments.